# Is there a good iPhone pie chart library which will produce good look 3d pie charts?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I can't find a library which will produce good looking 3d pie charts for the iphone?

I had a look at the core plot wiki and their pie didn't look that good...

[image]

Comment: There are many ways of theming plots in Core Plot, so you'll probably be able to achieve better results than that.  In any case, it's an open source framework, so you're free to help us improve the rendering quality of the pie charts.

Comment: have you any screen shots of better results ?

Comment: That pie chart wasn't created with Core Plot. From the sample page where you found it: "These are merely intended as targets for the framework, and do not indicate current capabilities."

Comment: Can you point me at any actual screen shots from core plot pie charts ?

Comment: Check out the CPTestApp-iPhone sample application in the Core Plot framework source code.  It should be kept up to date with the latest rendering code.  You can also try tweaking that sample to produce different visual effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also Fusion Charts, which is now HTML5. http://www.fusioncharts.com/

Answer (score 4):

There's an open-source class called `BNPieChart` available in [the moriarty library](https://github.com/tylerneylon/moriarty) which can produce pie charts like this:

[image: sample pie chart]
<sub>(source: [bynomial.com](http://bynomial.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Screen-shot-2010-12-10-at-10.41.31-AM1.png))</sub>

And also much smaller versions of course.  There's a post about it [here](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=104).

Comment: I'm unable to find any licensing information about the moriarty library. I'm assuming that it is free to use for commercial projects?

Comment: Yes, it's the apache 2 license, which is free to use for commercial projects.

Answer (score 3):

Besides NBPieChart proposed above, have a look at [XYPieChart](https://github.com/xyfeng/XYPieChart) it is a really good open source pie chart that looks very nice, are extremely simple, and contains animation for adding slices. Look at the screenshot of the demo project included:
[image: XYPieChart]

Comment: Is this library still under active development? The GIT repository doesn't show any change in a year.

Answer (score 1):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) has been recommended in other postings here on stackoverflow. It supports many standard data visualizations, including pie charts.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chart API is pretty good/popular. 
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ You will need a network connection though.

Answer (score 0):

If you want iOS native charting library you should check [ShinobyControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/).

If you want web-based, and also amazingly good charting library, maybe [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is the way to go.