# Code sample for charts and pie for iPad other than core-plot

Tags: iphone, ipad, charts

I am looking for charts and pie charts for iPad. Do you know some framework or sample code that I could use?
I know core-plot but I would like another one which makes 3D charts.

Comment: see this question for pie charts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125941/is-there-a-good-iphone-pie-chart-library-which-will-produce-good-look-3d-pie-char

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "3D pie chart for iPad" easily found this library:

http://iphone.orpi.pl/?p=20

Answer (score 0):

you can draw chart's of your choice there is one API is available in Google for that using that API you van show your chart in UIWebView here I am providing the URL for that.That Url Required different kind of parameter for that.
 http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/